# Lookup table with several different numeric types?

Tags: c++, embedded

### Background

For the UI of an embedded project have to display several variables on a screen and make it possible to edit those.

Currently, in my UI code, I have an enum containing the possible values, and I use a switch statement to find the currently selected one and show/edit it:

```
enum class ConfigPar {
    a,
    b,
    _last = lowValue,
};

void drawConfigScreen() {
    switch(currentPar) {
        case ConfigPar::a:
            // Draw "selected" box around a
            return;
        case ConfigPar::b:
            // Draw "selected" box around b
            return;
    }
}

void adjustConfigPar(delta) {
    switch (currentPar) {
        case ConfigPar::a:
            a += delta;
            return;
        case ConfigPar::b:
            b += delta;
            return;
    }
}
```

(Of course, I have more items than just `a` and `b`, and I omitted the specific UI drawing code because it's not relevant)

### Proposed solution

Now, I'd like to get rid of these switch statements because they are redundant; I have to repeat the list of options once in the enum, again in the code for drawing it to the display, and finally again in the code for adjusting the values.

I thought about having something like an array of pointers (or references) to these variables:

```
double* configPars[] = {
    &a,
    &b,
}
```

Then I can simply use that as a lookup table for the right variable to print/adjust:

```
void adjustConfigPar(delta) {
    configPars[currentPar] += delta;
}
```

### Problem

The problem here is that these variables I want to print/adjust are not all of the same type. Some are `double`s, some are `uint8_t`s, and some are `uint16_t`s. However, they are all numeric types, and operations I want to do to them are all the same: in-/de-crement them, and print them.

This is a problem of course since an array cannot contain items of different types.

I have thought about a couple of convoluted ways to solve this, but in the end they all have the same problem: that I need some sort of a heterogeneous container.

I'm working on a microcontroller here so I don't have access to the full Standard Library for e.g. std::variant.

Comment: How many parameters are we talking and are there multiple parameters of the same type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by @Errorist's answer, I ended up with this:

```
class ConfigPar {
    enum class ConfigParType {
        ui8,
        ui16,
        d,
    };
public:
    // The nested struct is in order to have an overloaded constructor for the type and the union, but avoid
    // having to strcopy the label
    struct Var {
        const ConfigParType type;
        union {
            uint8_t * const ui8;
            uint16_t * const ui16;
            double * const d;
        };

        Var(uint8_t *par) : type(ConfigParType::ui16), ui8(par) {}
        Var(uint16_t *par) : type(ConfigParType::ui16), ui16(par) {}
        Var(double *par) : type(ConfigParType::d), d(par) {}
    } var;

    char label[10];

    void adjust(int8_t delta) const {
        switch (var.type) {
            case ConfigParType::ui8:
                *var.ui8 += delta;
                return;
            case ConfigParType::ui16:
                *var.ui16 += delta;
                return;
            case ConfigParType::d:
                *var.d += static_cast<double>(delta) / 100;
                return;
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

i think this is what you meant

```
struct _Var{
    int i_type; //  macros TYPE_INT or TYPE_FLOAT etc
    
    union{
        int int_value;
        float float_value;
    };
};

_Var configPars[n_size];

void adjustConfigPar(int int_delta, float float_delta)
{
    _Var*curVar =   &configPars[currentPar];
    
    if(curVar->i_type==TYPE_INT)
        curVar->int_value   +=  int_delta;
    else if(curVar->i_type==TYPE_FLOAT)
        curVar->float_value +=  float_delta;
    else
        /* ... */;
}
```

Comment: FYI, refrain from leading underscores in symbol names.  Leading underscores are reserved for the compiler and you don't want to interfere with compiler symbols.

Comment: The `switch/case` statement may be more readable in this case than the `if-else-if` ladder.

Comment: I recommend using an `enum class` instead of the `int` for the type code.  An `int` has a wide range of values, including some you don't want.

Comment: Thanks, this pointed me in the right direction! I posted a somewhat modified solution as an answer that encapsulates the details in the class.